# RHEL/CentOS How to setup log messages when user gets locked out

Tags: centos, pam, rsyslog

so I am looking around and see there are messages on the log files for when a login attempt is failed, accepted, etc., but I don't see anything specifically for when an account is locked.

Could any one help on how to set that up, like a locked out message when a user reaches the limit re-tries on CentOS?

Comment: Interesting question. What version of CentOS or RHEL are you running?

Comment: CentOS 7. I am not sure if this is already in place and I just have to enable it or I have to set something up myself like, when account retries reaches limit create: account locklout message, for example.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is to check  **/var/log/secure**   file to see the successful and failed login attempts.And to collect all the records of bad login attempts by a user(john) you can use **lastb john** command.